# Свертка во втором и последующих слоях сверточной нейронной сети

Tags: нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только недавно начал разбираться в СНС. Тут же появился вопрос касательно 2ой свертки на картинке:

Получается у нас есть 16 фильтров и каждый из них мы прогоняем через каждый предыдущий сверточный слой, т.е поместили мы первый фильтр в верхний левый угол первого слоя, затем второго и т.д. до последнего 6го и потом складываем получившиеся значения и записываем их в значение карты признаков. После этого сдвигаем фильтр влево на единицу и проделываем то же самое?

Понимаю, что вопрос может быть не совсем понятен, но если кратко, то как происходит именно вторая свертка, когда на входе у нас 6 слоев?

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Нет сперва фильтром прошлись по данным 'сигналам'(картинке) полностью,выходит одна карта признаков,2-ым фильтром,выходит другая карта признаков,16 фильтров по одной картинке,выходит 16 карт признаков.

Comment: Складывать и находить среднее,уже по вышеуказанным картам признаков,тоже полностью проработав каждую.

Comment: Смотрите, представим у нас есть на входе 6 карт признаков и мы хотим выполнить свертку. У нас есть ещё допустим 5 ядер, следовательно на выходе должно быть 5 карт признаков. Так вот меня интересует следующее : глубина каждого фильтра определяется количеством входных карт признаков? То есть если на входе у нас 6 карт то глубина каждого фильтра следующего слоя будет равна 6, верно?

Comment: Давайте рассмотрим одно изображение,которое идет на вход,пусть оно (50:=<ряды>,60:=<колонки>)  и вот обрабатываем такую матрицу полностью последовательно 5-ю ядрами->5 карт признаков,отсюда дальше танцуйте)

Comment: Допустим мы получили эти 5 карт признаков и хотим сделать ещё одну свертку(пускай будет 5 ядер). Можете объяснить как происходит конкретно вторая свертка, когда у нас уже есть 5 карт признаков?

Comment: Хитрые вопросы)сам недавно этим занимаюсь,но по-моему по одной карте признаком 1-ым ядром,по 2-карте-2-м,по 3-3 и до 5->другие 5 карт признаков.

Comment: Наконец-то я нашел ответ. Оказывается, что глубина фильтра зависит от входа, т.е если у нас на входе 3 слоя RGB, то фильтр будет представлять собой массив h × h × c, где c - кол-во каналов. Следовательно, двигаясь далее по сети мы получаем, что глубина каждого фильтра будет равняться кол-ву входных карт признаков.

Comment: Вы планируете написать сверточную самостоятельно на ЯП?Давайте скооперируемся,чтобы проще было.

Comment: Идея хорошая, напишите на почту mikhailkuzmin420@gmail.com